# Plotly express color as legend based on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

is there a way to set the color of px.scatter with values of two different colors? i've looked in internet but i didn't find somthing.
Example of what i'm looking for:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [2,8,7,9,6],
        "B": ["F", "P", "P", "P", "P"],
        "C": [1,7,9,6,1],
        "D": ["F", "P", "P", "P", "F"],
    }
)
fig = px.scatter(df, x="A",y="C", **for color I want to have something like** color=['B','D'])
```

Is there a way to go?

[image]

Here the point A=6,C=1 is True for B but False for D… so i want it to be also blue

Comment: For example, with color='B', it is divided by color and legend, why do we need two columns?

Comment: @herbigjson There's always a way to go with plotly. But your desired output isn't exactly 100% clear. With your setup `x="A",y="C"`, ***one*** trace will be produced. But you're applying colors with two different conditions `'B', 'D'`. So I suspect a failed logic here somewhere. Do you have an exact idea of how your plot should look like? In that case, please consider including a screenshot of that. Even a sketch using MS Paint would be helpful.

Comment: i know it might be weird, but the reason i ask is, B shows if A passed or not, D if C passed or not. I want want the color (for example) to be rot if one of them (B or D) is failed. I want to compare both of 'B' and 'D' and then choose the color

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a very straight-forward to do that. But that doesn't mean it's impossible to visualize the story your aiming to tell here. I would consider `go.Scatter()` instead of `px.scatter()`, and then use two different symbols with two different colors. In the figure below, the marker is blue if both pass, red if both fail, and a red circle with a blue dot (or the opposite) if one passes and one fails.

#### Plot

[image]

#### Complete code

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [2,8,7,9,6],
        "B": ["F", "P", "P", "P", "P"],
        "C": [1,7,9,6,1],
        "D": ["F", "P", "P", "P", "F"],
    }
)

traces = ['B', 'D']
fig = go.Figure()
# colors = ['blue', 'red']
symbols = ['circle-open', 'circle']
sizes = [14,10]
for j, t in enumerate(traces):
    for i, xy in enumerate(df[t]):
        fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=[df['A'].iloc[i]], y=[df['C'].iloc[i]],
                                  mode = 'markers',
                                  legendgroup = t,
                                  showlegend = False,
                                  marker = dict(color = 'blue' if xy == 'P' else 'red' ,
                                                symbol = symbols[j],
                                                size = sizes[j])))
        
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

i did it

```
dfff = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [2,8,7,9,6],
        "B": ["F", "P", "P", "P", "P"],
        "C": [1,7,9,6,1],
        "D": ["F", "P", "P", "P", "F"],
    }
)

figg = px.scatter(dfff, x="A",y="C", hover_data=dfff.columns)
figg.update_traces(
    marker=dict(
        color=((dfff['B']=='F')|(dfff['D']=='F')).astype('float'),
        colorscale=[[0,'blue'],[1,'red']]
    )
)
figg.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.